# Iterative solutions with C++

Tags: c++

I have an assignment  to fill in the body of the following function(detectHappy) that will check whether a number is a happy number or not, for 10 cycles
(iterations) only. I have to:

-Find the sum of the digits of the number.

-Check the result obtained in point 1. If it is 1, assign value 1 to the variable 'finalNumber', else again execute point 1, till the number obtained is 1 or till the number of cycle increases to 10.

-Assign the iteration value to the variable 'cycle_no'.

I am not supposed to input, output or declare any additional functions. I just have to write the body of the function already declared there that will make it work on the shell offered in my course...

The programme I have attempted to write compiles but does not give the correct results. I am now short of ideas and I will be grateful for any assistance. Thank you in advance.

code:

```
/*Question      : Write your code to find whether the number is a happy 
number or not (for max 10 cycles).

int number      : The number to be determined whether it is happy or not

int finalNumber : Store the resultant value in this variable

int cycle_no    : Store the number of iterations done to determine whether 
the 'number' is happy or not */



void detectHappy(int number, int &finalNumber, int &cycle_no) {

//Write your solution code below this line


int sum = 0;
int i = 0;

do{
    sum += (number%10)*(number%10);
    number /=10;


    if (sum == 1){

        finalNumber = 1;
        break;

    }

    else {

        number = sum;
        i++;
    }

    cycle_no = i;


}

while (i < 10);
```

}

Comment: From one Charles to another, we won't do your homework for you on Stack Overflow!

Comment: hmmm while(10) huh?

Comment: `while (10)` is wrong. It's effectively an infinite loop as the numeric value `10` always evaluates to true in the while clause. Luckily you have a break in there. Still though if you wanted to do 10 iterations , that's not the way to do it. I would not use a do while loop here, just a regular for loop. `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, this also scopes your `i` variable only to the for loop.

Comment: `sum += r*r;`??

Comment: There are too many weird things going on here.  Its time to go back to the drawing board

Comment: @ PaulRooney thanks

Comment: There are several bugs in your code. You may never get the happy number. :)

Comment: `while(i<10){  //Code i++;  }` Can also be used. While loop works till the condition is true. **`while(10)`** is an infinite loop, since the syntax of while loop is `while(condition == true)` moreover 10 is a non zero number thus while(10) becomes infinite loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the do while loop and add a for loop

`int i;`
`for (i=0; i <10; i++)`

`{`

```
`Code stuff`
```

`}`

Comment: While for-loop is a good choice in this scenario, while and do-while are fine too. This is not the main issue with the OP's code.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain why changing the for loop works nor does it explain what was causing the original code to fail.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of bugs. Read the comments in the following code

```
void detectHappy(int number, int &finalNumber, int &cycle_no) {

    //Write your solution code below this line

    int r,   sum = 0; // Are you sure you need to declare r variable in here?!! You are modifying this variable inside the do-while(). 

    int i = 1; // where do you increment this value in your code?!!

   do { // the choice of do-while is fine in here because any integer number must have at least one digit. 

       r = number%10;
       sum += r*r; // Is this correct? 
       number = number/10;

       if (sum == 1){
           finalNumber = 1;
           break;
       } // there is an else statement in here. Read the instructions carefully. 


       if (sum !=1 || i != 10){ //  ( i != 10 ) this is always TRUE. You are not incrementing i in your code!!
            r = number%10;
            sum += r*r; // Is this correct? 
            number = number/10;
            number = sum;
       }

       cycle_no = sum; // Are you sure?!! cycle_no is iteration number NOT the sum. 
                       // Read this carefully: Assign the iteration value to the variable 'cycle_no'.

   }
   // this while is always true. It has no meaning in this sense. 
   while (10); //I want it to iterate successively for a maximum of 10 times if the lucky number is not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now did it using this method...

/*Question      : Write your code to find whether the number is a happy number or not (for max 10 cycles).

int number      : The number to be determined whether it is happy or not

int finalNumber : Store the resultant value in this variable

int cycle_no    : Store the number of iterations done to determine whether the 
'number' is happy or not */

void detectHappy(int number, int &finalNumber, int &cycle_no) {

```
//My code

 for (cycle_no=0; cycle_no < 10; cycle_no ++)
```

{

```
finalNumber = 0;

while (number)

{

  finalNumber += (number % 10)  * (number % 10);

  number /= 10;

}

if (finalNumber == 1)

  return;

number = finalNumber;
```

}

}